# How to send email through amazon SES in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send email through amazon SES in Rails Application.

That user story is

Here is my code.

config/environments/development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...

  # deviseの設定
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    port: 587,
    authentication: :login,
    user_name: '[SES UserName]',
    password: '[SEP Password]',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

app/mailer
（Here is only application_mailer.rb）

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout "mailer"
end
```

log/development.log

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 172.18.0.1 at 2017-09-27 02:55:35 +0000
...

<p>Hello test@gmail.com!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=EoGaE1UF2KjTNFLGHhvQ">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6247ms (ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)



Net::SMTPFatalError (553 <localhost:3000> Invalid email address.
):

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/smtp.rb:969:in `check_response'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/smtp.rb:937:in `getok'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/smtp.rb:837:in `mailfrom'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/smtp.rb:658:in `send_message'
mail (2.6.6) lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `block in deliver!'

...

puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 84ms (Views: 73.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I think that the center of the problem is this.

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (553 <localhost:3000> Invalid email address.):
```

But I can't resolve this problem.

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you request from Amazon to take your SES out of Sandbox mode or are you trying to send an email to a white listed one using previous confirmations?

Comment: Thanks! My SES is out of Sandbox mode now and I was trying to send email using white listed email.

Comment: Is it working now?